# Using @SpringApplicationConfiguration: How to set jobparameters in tests when using spring-batch and spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Is there a way, how I can define jobparameters in integration test, when using pure spring-boot with spring-batch?

When I define a simple Batch-Job in Spring-Boot and start it with `SpringApplication.run(args)`, I can pass my program-arguments in the run method.

Since I have Spring-Boot-Batch activated, those arguments are converted into `JobParameters` and are then passed to the job. This happens inside the class `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner`.

Afterwards, I can read this jobparameters via the jobexecution object.

Now, I would like to write a test, which starts a job almost the same way, as it will be in production. Therefore, I'm using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and write a test like the following one:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyBatchRootConfiguration.class})
@IntegrationTest({"aProp=aValue"})
public class MyBatchTestClass {
   @Test
   public void launchTest() {
   }
}
```

Note: `MyBatchRootConfiguration` defines the job and also adds the `@SpringBootApplication`, `@EnableBatchProcessing` and so on.

The problem I'm facing now: how can I pass arguments that will be converted to jobparameters? Is there a way, how this could be done?

As far as I have seen, the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` defines the loader as "SpringApplicationContextLoader". Therefore, adding `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` to a test class eventually calls the method `SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(...)`. In this method, the SpringContext is created and an instance of `SpringApplication` is also created. Finally, in the following line of `SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext()` (line 103 for version 1.2.4-RELEASE of spring-boot)

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = application.run();
```

run is called.

But contrary to the example of spring-boot-batch on https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

which in the end also calls the non-static run method of SpringApplication, there is no way to pass or to define `args`.

But this is crucial for spring-batch, since these `args`are converted to `JobParameters` in `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner`.

(`SpringApplication.run(String ... args)` calls `SpringAppplication.afterRefresh(..., String[] args)`calls `SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(..., String[] args)`calls `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(String ... args)`)

I guess there is no other way than adapting the JobLauncherCommandLinerRunner, or using it directly as in the following example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyBatchRootConfiguration.class})
@IntegrationTest({"aProp=aValue"})
public class MyBatchTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherCommandLineRunner runner;

   @Test
   public void launchTest() {
        String[] myArgs = new String[]{"jobParam1=value1"};
        runner.run(myArgs);
   }
}
```

I know, that I can use the `JobLauncherTestUtils`, but what if I would like to have a test, that starts a job "the spring-boot way"? `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is exactly for that.

But if we liked to use it to launch a Spring-Batch job, it looks to me as if we are missing a way to define the program-arguments and therefore to define jobparameters.

This leads me to the conclusion, that you cannot use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` to test a job, if you have a job that depends on jobparameters.

Are there any ideas or solutions?

Thanks

Hansjoerg

Comment: How are you launching your job within your test?

Comment: I edited my original post to clarify my intensions. I know, that I can use JobLauncherTestUtils to launch a job un tests. But what if I want to use @SpringApplicationConfiguration to test a job?  There is now way to pass program arguments and therefore to pass jobparameters.

Comment: 1.  What is `@SpringApplicationContext`?  I know about (and see you're trying to use) `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`, but am unfamiliar with the former.
2.  `@SpringApplicationContext` just bootstraps a context.  It doesn't add the Boot stuff.  What you're really asking for is a way to test the Spring framework piece and the only way to do that I'm aware of would be using something like Process.exec...

Comment: Sorry, I was rushing. I meant `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` not `@SpringApplicationContext`. Moreover, I was imprecise with `@MyBatchRootConfiguration` this contains the job defintion, as well as '@SpringBootApplication`, `@EnableBatchProcessing', '@ComponentScan'; basically this defines the whole boot stuff.  I edited my question again to be more precise. My questions stays the same: how can I define jobparameters, when writing a test annotated with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by launching a job "the boot way"?  Spring Boot still uses a `JobLauncher` that you can inject into your test yourself.  `@IntegrationTest` sets environment variables and does not pass application arguments.  I guess I'm trying to figure out what piece are you missing?  The conversion of the arguments to `JobParameter` instances?  If that's the case, you can inject the `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` into your test and just call that directly.

Comment: As stated in my original question, direct injection of `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` is a possible solution, which is actually working very well for me. By "launching the boot way" I meant being called via the SpringApplication.run method, as it is the case if you are using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration'. Wouldn't it be convenient to have something like '@SpringApplicationConfiguration(args="--debug -my.run.id=testrun1 ..")?

Comment: `SpringApplication.run` returns the context.  I guess there really isn't anything stopping you from just calling that from within your test method.  If you take that approach you wouldn't need the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` since `SpringApplication.run` builds a context for you...