# Launch Spring Batch Job problems in Spring Boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have defined multi Spring Batch Jobs in a Spring Boot application. For example, job1, job2. etc.

When I have written a junit test to one of these jobs. **The problem is when I reviewed the test output log,  I found it tried to launch all jobs defined in this project.**

I am using the latest stable Spring Boot 1.2.5, Spring Batch 3.0.4 in the projects.

The fragment code of junit test is following.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BatchApplication.class)
public class SubmitJobTest {

@Inject Job job1;

@Test
public void testLockJob() {

    logger.debug("lockId is @" + task.getLockId());

    JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("lockId", lockId.toString());
    try {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(this.job1, builder.toJobParameters());
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());

    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Some jobs I defined needs a JobParamters to run, so when I ran this test, other Jobs lauched and executed, then threw exceptions due to lack of the specific JobParamters.

I have tried to add `@Named` to Job and inject it by an unique name, but got the same result.

**I resolved this issue myself.** After added `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` into `application.yml`, it works.

- The jobs are not launched by default.
- When ran the tests, it worked as I expected, only one job launched.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. I asked the same question a couple of weeks ago:
[Using @SpringApplicationConfiguration: How to set jobparameters in tests when using spring-batch and spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181947/using-springapplicationconfiguration-how-to-set-jobparameters-in-tests-when-us)

You have to directly use the JobLauncherCommandLineRunner:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyBatchRootConfiguration.class})
@IntegrationTest({"aProp=aValue"})
public class MyBatchTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherCommandLineRunner runner;

   @Test
   public void launchTest() {
        String[] myArgs = new String[]{"jobParam1=value1"};
        runner.run(myArgs);
   }
}
```

Comment: Note: if you have more than one runable job in the context, you have to define the the property "spring.batch.job.names=job1" in order to start just job1 in the test (@IntegrationTest({"spring.batch.job.names=job1"}).

Comment: The problem is why Spring Boot launches the Jobs automatically at start up, I need to run my Jobs manually. It is possible to forbid it to launch the Jobs?

Comment: Hi hansjoerg, I think I resolved this issue myself by adding `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` into application.properties to disable the launching automation.